# Get a keyword string from a meta tag using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to pull a keyword from a meta data og:title, the keyword is always the same, but will appear in a different placement within the title.

```
document.querySelector("meta[property='og:title']").getAttribute("Sorry");
```

^return is null.

Thanks!

Comment: what does the actual meta tag look like

Comment: the html meta data is og:title

<div class="Breadcrumb" id="ProductBreadcrumb">
 <ul id="breadcrump_ul" class="last">
 <li><a href="link">Home</a></li><li><a href="/recommended">Recommendedations</a></li><li>
Sorry but this product is out of stock</li>
</ul>
<script>

Comment: Post the tag in your question

Comment: tag for og:title  "Sorry but this product is out of stock"

Comment: @epascarello any idea?